# React native flatlist pull from bottom functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know how to implement a "pull to refresh" from the top of the list functionality using the `onRefresh` prop,is there a way to do something similar for the bottom end of the list,so when i "pull" from the bottom would trigger a function ?

The `onEndReached` prop does'nt really work as i would like,since it runs a function everytime you reach the end of the list,i dont want that,i want nothing to run unless i "pull" from the bottom.

I tried to invert the flatlist using the `invert` prop,which makes use of the `onRefresh` prop when pulling from the bottom(its upside down),and it works perfectly,but i want to have them both.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,i just added a negative value to `onEndReachedThreshold` prop,so `onEndReachedThreshold={-0.5}` will run the `onEndReached` function when "pulling" to as much as half of the flatlist height.